# Preselecting value in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Texbox is dynamically filled with a remote call using Select2 and how do I set preselected value. Here is the code

```
<input type="hidden" id="e6">

$("#e6").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for a movie",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term, // search term 
                page_limit: 10, }; 
        }, 
        results: function (data, page) { 
                return {results: data};
        }
    }
});
```

I tried this to preselect value 1049

`$('#e6').select2('val', '1049');`

but this doesn't set the value on the textbox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In case anybody wants to know how to solve this

```
$("#e6").select2('data', {id: '1049', text: 'MyLabel'});
```

Comment: you have a typo - $("#e6")

Comment: @smith how to pre-select more than 1 value ??

Comment: @VikashSingh use this: `[ {id: '1049', text: 'MyLabel'} , {id: '10', text: 'Mybel'} ]`

Answer (score 6):

The solution that worked for me (and that is decribed in the documentation) was:

```
$('#mySelect2').val('1'); // Select the option with a value of '1'
$('#mySelect2').trigger('change'); // Notify any JS components that the value changed
```

Answer (score 4):

in 2019 this worked for me

```
    // Create a DOM Option and pre-select by default~
    var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, true, true);
    // Append it to the select
    $('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work with

```
$("#e6").val("input id of the select2 option here").trigger("change")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use initSelection method

```
initSelection: function(element, callback) {
callback({id: 1, text: 'default selection with id 1' });
},
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/493) and loading remote data section [here](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: this doesn't work, initSelection is only called when the hidden input you attach to has a non-empty value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

for multiple selection...

```
var li = $("#e6");
li.select2({
    placeholder: "Placeholder"
});

var unselected = li.find('option:not(:selected)');
var selected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < unselected.length; i++) {
    selected[i] = { id: unselected[i].value, text: unselected[i].text };
}
li.select2('data', selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had troubles with it too.

Since the select2 is filled when user inputs some text via AJAX, it starts empty. So the previous answers of the type `.val('')` **don't apply**.
For example:

```
$('#e6').val('1'); // Select the option with a value of '1'
$('#e6').trigger('change'); // Notify any JS components that the value changed
```

this won't work since there is no `.val` to select from.

Then you need to preload some data to the select2. The selected answer which tries to preload the data did **not** work for me:

```
$("#e6").select2('data', {id: '1049', text: 'MyLabel'});
```

(I guess the code and behavior of the plugin has changed since the answer was made and accepted)

---

Then you solve this in 2 ways:

1. You can force it to be preloaded by the AJAX using the [code in the documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2).
2. You can preload data and select it with JS. In my case I needed this select2 prefilled with preselected elements while maintaining the AJAX search.

I used the following:

```
select2 = $('#e6'); 
var option = new Option('MyLabel', 1049, true, true); //The true vars are for preselecting
select2.append(option); //You can repeat this and the previous line for multiselect
select2.trigger('change'); //Call change event so the control updates
```

The same in fewer lines:

```
var option = new Option('MyLabel', 1049, true, true); //The true vars are for preselecting. 1049 is the id.
$('#e6').append(option).trigger('change'); //Append option and call change event
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    if (window.formPrefill) {
      // setTimeout to force script to run when all the stack on doc.ready is complete.
      setTimeout(() => $(".js-select2-companies").select2('data', window.formPrefill), 10);
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you can do it like this for multiple preselection:

```
$('#mySelect2').val(['1', '2']); 
$('#mySelect2').trigger('change'); // Notify any JS components that the value changed
```

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Answer (score 0):

in my case, my selected values were saved with comma seperated in my database so i used this approach and it worked for me

```
        var ele = document.getElementById('farmProduce');
        let val =ele.getAttribute('value')
        for(i=0; i < len; i++){ 
            ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML + '<option value="' + farm_produce[i].name + '"' + (val.includes(farm_produce[i].name) ? 'selected="'+true+'"' : null)+'>' + farm_produce[i].name + '</option>';
        }
```

so essentially, just setting the selected attribute to true and false for each option did the tricks for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31395218)